# What gem can I use to optimize and compress any file in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand there are several gems for image optimizations. However, I haven't come across any gem that will optimize or compress images files such jpeg, as well pdfs and doc files. Is there any gem which will optimize and compress any such files?

Comment: see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/gzipped-images-is-it-worth

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is a broad concept. Compressing images, for example, is optimization in itself. These are inheritently not part of a gem or language library but proper dedicated utilities like [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Gems like [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions) lets you upload an image and resize it on the go. Then there is ImageMagick's ruby wrapper, [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick).

You can look for similar functions for documents/pdf.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the all the gems you've mentioned. I was hoping to find one gem to optimize them all.Is there no such gem. Forgive me if I am limited in my understanding.

Comment: There is no such collective gem I know of. Also, having such a gem will be like having a big toolbox rather than a lightweight gem. Hope it helps